# Issue with a expression capturing groups

Tags: regex, perl, expression, capture

I have some data like this

```
Wed Mar 18 15:16:10 2015 eth0:1 109.224.232.219 up (not currently mapped)
Wed Mar 18 15:18:12 2015 eth0:1 109.224.232.219 down (not responding)
Wed Mar 18 15:20:46 2015 eth0:1 109.224.232.219 up (not currently mapped)
Wed Mar 18 15:22:52 2015 eth0:1 109.224.232.219 down (not responding)
Wed Mar 18 15:24:26 2015 eth0:1 109.224.232.219 up (not currently mapped)
```

I am trying to capture the IP and the date string on each line, I thought I could just do anything before the word eth and then my IP check, but this isn't working. Have I mis understood the concept of capture groups?

Is there a sensible way to get this data from 1 regex?

```
(^(.*?)eth)(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3})
```

Any help would be appreciated.

This is an image of the regex currently

https://www.debuggex.com/i/BaXnqh2DzRhUCph8.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're almost there. You just need to add `.*?` after `eth` so that it would match the characters present in-between `eth` and the ip-address.

```
^(.*?)eth.*?\b(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3})
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/jX1jL8/2)

If you don't want the space before `eth`  not to be  captured by group 1 then you could change your regex like this,

```
^(.*?)\s+eth.*?\b(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3})
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/jX1jL8/3)

Comment: I had to wait 8 minutes :P

Answer (score -1):

Sometimes, people ignore what a well-defined sequence of characters a dotted-decimal IP representation is. I have almost *no* problems identifying an IP when I fully detail a proper IP octet.

```
my $octet  = qr/\b(?:0|1\d{0,2}|2(?:[0-4]\d?|5[0-5]?|[6-9])?|[3-9]\d?)\b/;
my ( $foctet = "$octet" ) =~ s/0[|]//;
```

And then on top of that, I specify that a IP address is a set of four octets, separated by a dot.

```
my $ip_regex = qr/($foctet(\.$octet){3})/;
```

This little beauty will almost always pull for me anything that is a valid IP from any file.

Along with this, dates can be specified with greater specification. And again, following this specification, what you get will almost inevitably be a date:

```
my $dow            = qr/\b(?:Fri|Mon|Sat|Sun|Thu|Tue|Wed)\b/;
my $mon            = qr/\b(?:Apr|Aug|Dec|Feb|Jan|Jul|Jun|Mar|May|Nov|Oct|Sep)\b/;
my $day            = qr/\b(?:[012]\d?|3[01]?|[4-9])\b/;
my $hr24           = qr/\b(?:[01]\d?|2[0-3])\b/;
my $minsec         = qr/\b(?:[0-5]\d)\b/;
my $datetime_regex = qr/$dow\s+$mon\s+$day\s+$hr24:$minsec:$minsec\s+\d+/;
```

So simply using both regexes against the source line, you get what you want without a whole lot of backtracking needed.

```
my @date_parts = $line =~ /$datetime_regex/;
my ( $ip )     = $line =~ /$ip_regex/;
```

In fact, if performance is a concern, I saw numerous failures in the single regex with the non-greedy match, whereas the the ip regex succeeds on first try. The regex engine finds '.' at offset 35 and starts back at position 32.

However, the following, does not fail once for both. Just an indication of how it can help to specify your expressions to the expected range of data:

```
my ( $dt, $ip ) = m/($datetime_regex)\s+eth\d:\d+\s+($ip_regex)/;
```